# Insert/update query

Tags: php, mysql

When trying to insert or update, nothing goes into the database.
This is the table layout

```
(
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `thesis_Name` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
 `abstract` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
 `complete` int(2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 KEY `user_id` (`user_id`)
)
```

As you can see the id is the unique key. The user_id is what the session looks at. I want it to be possible for the user_id to have two rows so only id should be unique and therefore that should be the key that is looked for on whether to insert or update.
This is what I have been using:

```
 if (empty($err)) {
        $id= mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['id']);
        $thesis_Name = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['thesis_Name']);
        $abstract = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['abstract']);

$user_id = intval($_SESSION['user_id']);
$query = sprintf("
  INSERT INTO
    `thesis`(`id`,`user_id`, `thesis_Name`, `abstract`)
  VALUES
    ('%s','%s', '%s', '%s')
  ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
   `thesis_Name` = VALUES(`thesis_Name`),
   `abstract` = VALUES(`abstract`)
      ", $id, $user_id, $thesis_Name, $abstract);
```

If there is noway around it then the user_id can be unique too, only 1 row per user

Comment: What happens? Are errors reported? What is your concrete question? Or should we just join guessing with you?

Comment: For the love of god, use parameterized queries

Comment: If you don't know what Keith means, or why he's saying it, read about [Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com)

Comment: Where do you get the `$id` value from then? If there can be two rows per `user_id`, would it not be easier to make a column for that (rownumber enum(1,2)) and make a unique key on (user_id,rownumber) ?

Comment: no errors. it just doesn't go into the table

Comment: id is just an autoinc value created when inserted

Answer (score 1):

Can you show us final query ? With something like this after `$query = sprintf(...)`:

```
echo $query
```

Maybe a simple quote in your `$abstract`? You can use `mysql_real_escape_string()` to advoid it :

```
$thesis_Name = mysql_real_escape_string($thesis_Name);
$abstract = mysql_real_escape_string($abstract);
```

Answer (score 0):

1. to get an error from mysql, you have to use `mysql_error()` function.
2. you have to escape strings your are placing in the query.
3. there is no use for the sprintf() here.

.

```
$user_id     = intval($_SESSION['user_id']);    
$id          = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['id']);
$thesis_Name = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['thesis_Name']);
$abstract    = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['abstract']);

$query       = "INSERT INTO thesis (id, user_id, thesis_Name, abstract)
                VALUES ('$id','$user_id', '$thesis_Name', '$abstract')
                ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
                    `thesis_Name` = VALUES(`thesis_Name`),
                    `abstract` = VALUES(`abstract`)";

mysql_query($query) or trigger_error(mysql_error()." ".$query);
```

if you are using mysql* functions.

However, this is quite unusual approach
usually we decide which query to use based on the PHP logic, like this

```
if ($_POST['id']) {
    $query = "INSERT..."
} else {
    $query = "UPDATE..."
}
```

Comment: thank you for your help. with this it adds the insert but adds another row (with same_id and different id) instead of updating what I inserted

Comment: so with the top code now, a second row isn't added but the data doesn't change. When pressing save, it just redirects me to the correct page. do you suggest to try your second piece of code then?

Comment: just for this moment change trigger_error() with die(); may be there is an error displayed by you just don't see it. Let's make it certain

Comment: have you left $id in the query unquoted for a reason? it says undefined now

Comment: by mistake. it shouldn't be undefined though. do you have it in the HTML form?

Comment: so when defining it, we go back to adding another row to the table with the same user_id different id (this is auto inc)

Comment: if you define it with 0,  it will create new record. if you define it with existing record id, it will replace it. I am not sure what is your relationship with user_id. So, better go with the second code.

Comment: thats what I want, to replace it

Comment: have you got your code to work? if not - you are not required to accept an answer, you may leave it unanswered all right